# How to get multiple y axis in chart.js?

Tags: javascript, charts

I have tried the following to display two y axis on one line chart. However, the charts don't seem to appear once I implement this.

```
var options = {
                type: "line",
                data: {
                    labels: timelist,
                    datasets: [
                        {label: "Ambient Temp", data: temp_amb_data, backgroundColor: "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)", borderWidth: 1, borderColor: "rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)",id='left-y-axis'},
                        {label: "Ambient Humidity", data:amb_hum_data, backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)", borderWidth: 1, borderColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)",id='right-y-axis'},
                        {label: "Booth Temp", data: temp_col, backgroundColor: "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)", borderWidth: 1, borderColor: "rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)",id='left-y-axis'},
                        {label: "Booth Humidity", data: hum_data, backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)", borderWidth: 1, borderColor: "rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)",id='right-y-axis'}
                    ]
                },
                options: {
                    legend:{position:'right'},
                    animation: {tension: {duration: 1000, easing: "linear", from: 1, to: 0, loop: true}},
                    scales: {yAxes:[{ id:'left-y-axis',type='linear',position:'left'},{id:'right-y-axis',type='linear',position:'right'}]}
                }
            };

            var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
            var chart = new Chart(ctx, options);
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You should look at the error message you're likely getting, your `JSON` isn't valid, i.e. you need to replace your `=` with `:` like the rest of `options`. If you still need help showing your chart, you need to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. It was really silly if me not to notice it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues I see on your snippet are:

1. You are missing a few settings on your Chart.js configuration.
2. The provided JSON is not valid.
3. Additionally, it is not easy to reproduce the error. Try providing a Codepen example.

I have created this Codepen snippet with a Chart and two Y axes: https://codepen.io/adelriosantiago/pen/wvGxeGB

See the second Y axis inside `options.scales.yAxes`. Can you try it with your `dataset` data and see if  it fits your needs? If it doesn't please fork the Codepen and provide the link.

In the second CodePen you provided the only issue found is the invalid Chart.JS configuration. Specifically the key `yAxisId` which should be `yAxisID`. Small but important difference. The fixed Codepen is here: https://codepen.io/adelriosantiago/pen/MWyqWdr (I added a negative value on the second axis to easily differentiate `min` and `max`)

Comment: Hi, could you please check my codepen. the secondary y axis appears but it doesnot seem to have the correct points and also does not change dynamically. 
<https://codepen.io/_aishwariya_/pen/NWNLWyN>

Comment: Hi @coder_bg, I have added the reason and a fixed Codepen in my answer above.

Comment: Hi, thank you, it works perfectly now. I know this is not a correct thread to continue, could you just have a look at my <https://codepen.io/_aishwariya_/pen/YzqOPXz?editors=1010> and suggest me about why the time slider is not working?

Comment: @coder_bg Lets open a new question so that anyone can answer =]. Also I don't any slider on the CodePen you posted?

Comment: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63949740/how-do-i-change-my-xaxis-according-to-my-range-slider-in-chart-js> here is the question. Please have a look. Thanks.